# python find-replace non-latin word in string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do this:

`val = re.sub(r'\b' + u_word +'\b', unicode(new_word), u_text)`

(All strings are non-latin.)

It does not work, at all!.

Is it possible to find-replace non-latin words (whole words) in a non-latin text with regex?
How?

EDIT:

If you want to test try these strings:

```
>>> u_word = u'αβ'
>>> u_text = u'αβγ αβ αβγδ δαβ'
>>> new_word = u'χχ'
>>> val = re.sub(r'\b' + u_word +r'\b', unicode(new_word), u_text)
>>> val
u'\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3 \u03b1\u03b2 \u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4 \u03b4\u03b1\u03b2'
>>> u_text
u'\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3 \u03b1\u03b2 \u03b1\u03b2\u03b3\u03b4 \u03b4\u03b1\u03b2'
>>>
```

Comment: do you mind adding u_word and new_word to be able to test

Comment: The second `\b` must be in a raw string... Otherwise it will interpret as `\x08`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the **`re.UNICODE`** flag to `sub`, like so:

```
val = re.sub(r'\b' + u_word + r'\b', unicode(new_word), u_text, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

`\b` is a word boundary. Without the `re.UNICODE` flag, a "word" contains only characters from the set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so `αβ` isn't seen as a "word". For more information see [the `re` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#module-re) (specifically `\b`, `\w`, and `re.UNICODE`).

FYI:

- If `new_word` is already a unicode string (as in your example), `unicode(new_word)` is superfluous, [it returns `new_word` unmodified](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#unicode).
- In Python 3.x, unicode is no longer a special case. Your code would have worked as is in Python 3.x (minus `unicode()` which was removed because it's no longer necessary).